# g++ how to avoid error on -Werror=address-of-packed-member for specific function parameter

Tags: c++, g++, memory-alignment

When compiling with `-Werror=address-of-packed-member` taking the address of an unaligned element in a packed struct is an error, as it should. Nevertheless, there may be cases where you know it is safe to take such unaligned pointer and want to allow it for a parameter in a particular function call.

**Is there any syntax that would let g++ know a function argument should accept unaligned pointers with no warning/error?** I know I could disable the error/warning, but that will hide also mistakes I may have in other parts of my code.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T> void memcpy(T* dst, T* src)
{
    memcpy(dst,src,sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
  struct {
      char c;
      int d;
  }__attribute__((packed)) v;
  v.d=10;
  int e;
  memcpy(&e,&v.d);
  std::cout<<e;
}
```

Results in the following error, but is perfectly valid code, because the type information is only used to obtain the size, but the pointer is cast to `void*` before use.

```
error: taking address of packed member of ‘main()::<unnamed struct>’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Werror=address-of-packed-member]
   18 |       memcpy(&e,&v.d);
```

I'm looking for a mechanism similar to the usage of `(void)argv;` to avoid error with `-Werror=unused-parameter`.

Comment: `but is perfectly valid code` Not necessarily on all systems.

Comment: If the order of struct values is unimportant, you may re-order them from wider to smaller types and avoid memcpy: `struct {
int d;
char c;
}__attribute__((packed)) v; e = v.d`

Comment: @eerorika I do not know if it may be undefined behaviour, but in systems able to memcpy on any byte alignment I can't see why the code above would break.

Comment: @AndresR There's no guarantee that `int*` could point to an unaligned address.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can always take a pointer `void*` of any alignment, so the solution may be along the lines of

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T> void memcpy(T* dst, void* src)
{
    memcpy(dst,src,sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
  struct {
      char c;
      int d;
  }__attribute__((packed)) v;
  v.d=10;
  int e;
  memcpy(&e,&v.d);
  std::cout<<e;
}
```

which no longer gives any errors/warnings.